# App (or OSX) changing Accessibility setting by itself

Tags: macos, permission, dropbox, accessibility

Dropbox requests (though doesn't seem to *require*, i.e. it runs without) accessibility/control computer permission (under Security -> Privacy).

Removing permission manually (requiring admin password), then rebooting, leads to permission being granted again. Which doesn't seem to be the way it *should* be, right?

Any idea what mechanism allows the app to grant itself Accessibility permission? Alternatively, if it's not Dropbox, but OSX itself, why would it change the value?